# Microsoft Graph People API failed to search across big group

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph People API, seems like it cannot search across big team.

My app has permission **User.ReadBasic.All**.

For example, I am in Office group, I cannot search someone in Windows group.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people/?$search="Terry Myerson"
```

It will return

```
{
    "value": []
}
```

**EDIT**: I got answer from Marc, but I still feel it should return not relevant people and just let the results rank behind. So I create a feature request. You can [track here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/1890).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/people` endpoint only surfaces "relevant" people. From the [docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/people_example):

> Microsoft Graph applications can use the People API to retrieve the people who are most relevant to a user. Relevance is determined by the user’s communication and collaboration patterns and business relationships.

Unless you have relevant communication/interaction with Terry, he won't show up in your collection.

Comment: Thanks, is there a similar API can search the rest of people who are not relevant with me? For example, a name start with ‘terr’. Something like `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$search="terr"`

Comment: You can use the `$filter` param for "starts with": `/v1.0/users?$filter=startsWith(displayName, 'terr')`